# The Geometry Node 'Vector rotate' doesn't keep the relative rotation of an object

Tags: geometry-nodes, transform-orientation

When I add an object with the GN 'Object Info' and the option 'Relative' this one only just keep the location but not the rotation.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my Geometry Nodes, the 'Vector Rotate' in the X-axis, or the the way I use the 'Object Info' 'Relative'?

How can I rotate a vector and have it take into account the rotation of the object?

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? if i rotate the finger on x axis...all moves...so it does take it into account. Can you pls be a bit more specific?

Comment: If you rotated the finger in z axis, the GN that uses 'Vector rotate' will ignore that rotation and continue to bend in the same way. In the first image the finger is still bent the same even though I have rotated it in the Z axis by 45 degrees

Comment: Thanks @Chris :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to rephrase the question I found how to solve the problem.

[image]

You only need to retrieve the 'Rotation' parameter from the 'Object Info' and perform an Euler rotation.

And now if I rotate my finger along the Z axis, the GN works.

[image]

Comment: This GIF has the most interesting aliasing I've seen in a long while. https://i.imgur.com/7Zn52Mw.png